# Appending Many Numpy Arrays to List Extremely Slow

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, garbage-collection

I have roughly half a million numpy arrays saved on disk as .npy files. Each has 5 columns and anywhere between a few hundred and a few million rows. I now wish to read them all back into memory on a machine with 3TB RAM. My question is: What is the fastest way to do this?

I've tried using `np.load` in a list comprehension, which runs along very swiftly until I reach just over ~800 GB in memory, after which point the reading slows almost to a crawl. The loading speed does not appear to slow at a linear or a geometric pace; it just suddenly drops off a cliff around the 800 GB point. Here's the simple code I'm executing:

```
def read_numpy_arrays():
        '''Read in all ngram arrays created by the previous stage, and store them in memory of master process'''
        gc.disable()
        ngram_arrays = [np.load(i) for i in glob.glob("outfiles/*/*/*.npy")]
        gc.enable()
        return ngram_arrays
```

I have also tried removing the garbage collection lines, but that didn't make a big difference.

When I call `top` after about 10 hours of processing, I can see that I am now only adding to the list every few minutes.

[image]

I'm using the Anaconda Python 2.7 on Redhat, and the directory from which I'm reading is only about half full:

```
df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       5.4T  2.5T  2.7T  49% /
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this sudden crash in performance, or what I can do to resolve it? Any help others can offer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check your memory values, I don't think you have 3TB or ram, perhaps 3GB?

Comment: Looks like something is thrashing the memory, perhaps the very program you're running, which should load something like ~2.5TB of data in-memory when finished -- which is quite a significant fraction of your total RAM.  Do you absolutely need to hold all that thing in-memory?  Maybe there's a system-wide limit on how much memory a user/process can access?

Comment: Thanks @CongMa. I've used a slightly different implementation on the same machine to aggregate ~2.7 TB in RAM within a single process, and that had no performance crash like I'm seeing here. Previously, I was passing results from multiprocessing processes back into the master process memory, but now I'm reading results of spawned processes from disk (because multiprocessing fails when passing huge np arrays back to master process). Holding everything in memory simultaneously isn't necessary, but gives a big performance boost.

Comment: So does that mean you've fixed it by not throwing large numpy arrays back?  Can you edit your question to reflect this progress?  Or am I reading it wrong...?

Comment: Not quite, @CongMa; I can fix the workflow by keeping smaller arrays in memory and never writing any numpy arrays to disk, but that won't resolve the question, which is: Why does performance tank mysteriously when reading lots of numpy arrays from disk? If I need to subdivide the workflow in the future, it will be helpful to write the arrays to disk then read them back into memory rather than keep everything in memory for the full duration, so I'd like to unravel this mystery.

Comment: Hmm.. Run tests with [`memory_profiler`](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler)?

Comment: maybe you should check if you're experiencing an increase of disk IO or page faults when you go over the performance cliff.